# RSelenium: Click on the nth iteration of a class in a nested div

Tags: r, selenium, css-selectors, rselenium

I'm trying to click on the 4th iteration of a svg of class "MuiSvgIcon-root.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium.css-10dohqv". You can see from the search bar at the bottom that this is the 4th of 16 times this class type appears in the code.

[image]

I figure this code should work:

```
logout <- remDr$findElement(using="css selector", value="svg.MuiSvgIcon-root.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium.css-10dohqv > :nth-of-type(4)")
logout$clickElement()
```

However, it's selecting a different element (the 5th).  Further, R seems to think that this is the last element of this class type.  If I use `nth-of-type(5)`, I get the following error message `Selenium message:Unable to locate element`.

Any idea why this is happening or how to click on this element?  Is the problem related to the existence of `<div role="button" tabindex="0" class>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to click the button using `findElements` (plural) to get a list of the number of times this element occurred in the code, and then I selected the 5th element on the list.  Note that I'm using a different css element (the list was shorter so it was just easier).

```
logout <- remDr$findElements(using="css", value="button.MuiButtonBase-root._1rIDE.MuiIconButton-root.MuiIconButton-sizeMedium._1mHFW.css-1yxmbwk")
logout[[5]]$clickElement()
```

I'm dissatisfied with this because I don't understand why `nth` doesn't work. I also don't understand why this was the 5th element (under "Inspect", if I use control+F, this element only appears 4 times).  But, this does work.